# SearchView очистка при открытии

Tags: android, listview, filter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть фрагмент со списком и SearchView. Фильтрация работает, все в порядке.
Проблема: при переходе на другой фрагмент, а затем обратно (BackStack) в SearchView остается предыдущий запрос. Но сам список не отфильтрован, так как события ввода не было. Мне нужно или очищать список или сделать, чтобы строка запроса применялась.
Для очистки в onViewCreated пробовал делать **svName.setQuery("", false);**
Не работает. Подскажите как сделать.

Код ниже вызывается в onViewCreated:

```
   //  Фильтрация списка
    svName = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.svName);
    svName.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // String text = edtName.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            Log.d(myLog, "Фильтр  - " + newText);
            myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

При переходе на другой фрагмент, попробуйте выполнять это:

```
svName.setQuery("", false);
svName.onActionViewCollapsed();
svName.collapseActionView();
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо